# TCP Server response timeout

Tags: java, tcp

I have been tasked with getting a simple TCP Client to timeout. The client works as expected, however I cannot seem to get the client to timeout when the client does not receive an input for 3 seconds or more.
I have a basic understanding of SO_TIMEOUT, but can't get it to work here.
Please help

Here is my code:
**TCPClient**

```
private static final String host = "localhost";
    private static final int serverPort = 22003;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        try
        {
            System.out.println("You are connected to the TCPCLient;" + "\n" + "Please enter a message:");
            BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Socket client = new Socket(host, serverPort);
            client.setSoTimeout(3000);
            while(true)
            {
                DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                String input = inFromUser.readLine();
                outToServer.writeBytes(input + "\n");
                String modedInput = inFromServer.readLine();
                System.out.println("You Sent: " + modedInput);
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Slept-in");
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SocketTimeoutException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Timed Out Waiting for a Response from the Server");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setSoTimeout` doesn't do what you think it does. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29):

> With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the
>   InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this
>   amount of time.

It's a timeout for reads from the socket, so `reads()` will return after 3 seconds even if there's no data. It's not a timeout for socket inactivity - i.e. the socket won't disconnect after being idle for 3 seconds.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll look into building a thread to calculate 3 seconds, unless you can suggest something a little less code-intensive?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a separate thread. You can setSoTimeout of 3 seconds, and close the socket if you catch the timeout exception (meaning that no data arrived for three seconds). You can handle the outbound traffic using the same mechanism - when the timeout exception is caught, just check if you've sent anything in the last 3 seconds. If so, then don't close the socket, and go back to read().